# Pixel values in green channel aren't as expected when using PIL in python

Tags: python, numpy, colors, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am experimenting to see if I can get pixel values out of an image. But the image values I'm getting out aren't what I expected them to be. *(Specifically, the green channel for the green triangle gives me a weird value)*

To break this down, I'm running 2 small experiments.

1) I plot 2 triangles: pink alongside red. I get the pixel values I'd expect.

2) I plot 2 triangles: pink alongside green. I **don't** get values I expect.

So for the first scenario, I know that beforehand, I'd expect to get these pixel values back:

[image]

So using this simple function, I will plot these triangles:

```
def get_pixel_vals(to_plot):
    im = Image.new("RGB", (140,125)) 

    for a_vertice in to_plot:
        ImageDraw.Draw(im).polygon(a_vertice[1], outline=a_vertice[0], fill=None)

    pix = np.array(im)
    for channel_num, color_channel in enumerate(['red', 'green', 'blue']):
        channel_list = []
        channel_array = pix[..., channel_num]  # gets you the R, G, or B channel of the numpy array
        print '********* \n', color_channel,  'channel, min:', channel_array.min()
        channel_list.append(channel_array.flatten().tolist())
        channel_flat = [item for alist in channel_list for item in alist]
        print color_channel, 'num unique values:', len(set(channel_flat))
        print color_channel, 'values:', list(set(channel_flat))
        imshow(im)

to_plot_pink_red = [ ['pink', [(25,25), (25,100), (50,100), ]] , ['red', [(100,25), (100,100), (125, 100)]] ]
get_pixel_vals(to_plot_pink_red)
```

And I get:

[image]

```
********* 
red channel, min: 0
red num unique values: 2
red values: [0, 255]
********* 
green channel, min: 0
green num unique values: 2
green values: [0, 192]
********* 
blue channel, min: 0
blue num unique values: 2
blue values: [0, 203]
```

Perfect! Exactly what I'd expect!

So what about if I plot a pink triangle alongside a green triangle?

I'd expect

[image]

and I almost get it...but not quite!

```
to_plot_pink_green = [ ['pink', [(25,25), (25,100), (50,100), ]] , ['green', [(100,25), (100,100), (125, 100)]] ]
get_pixel_vals(to_plot_pink_green)
```

[image]

```
********* 
red channel, min: 0
red num unique values: 2
red values: [0, 255]
********* 
green channel, min: 0
green num unique values: 3
green values: [0, 192, 128]
********* 
blue channel, min: 0
blue num unique values: 2
blue values: [0, 203]
```

I expect `[0, 192, 255]` for the G channel...but why am I getting `[0, 192, 128]`? 
Why did the 255 get turned into a 128?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color names you're using are defined in [ImageColor.py](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/b9f688301a1c9fa057d2892ba2abb2fa53ba066d/src/PIL/ImageColor.py). `"green"` is mapped to `"#008000"` which is why you're only seeing 128 in the green channel. If you want an rgb value of 0, 255, 0 you can use `"lime"` or just `"#00ff00"`.